# How programmable detect if a user has admin rights (can run installer)

Tags: c++, installation, windows-vista, detection, administrator

in my code I need to detect if current user has rights to install other application (other application VC2005 redist. package)... and it should work on Vista.

As I understand CheckTokenMembership or IsAdministrator do not give a complete solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not the way UAC works, 99.99% of the time the answer will be No.  You get access by asking for it.  Include [a manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) in your installer.  The redist installer already has that manifest.

Answer (score 1):

While the currently logged in user  might not have rights to install, they may still be prompted with an authentication dialog ("over the shoulder" install). If a valid username and password is entered on this dialog, they can install. So this isn't something you can reliably check as the user is technically "allowed" but **only** once they enter a correct username/password.

Your best solution is to attempt to elevate and fail gracefully if that fails :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PrivilegeCheck function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379304(VS.85).aspx